# Text on top of a Gallery slideshow with Squarespace

Tags: jquery, css, position, slideshow, squarespace

I'm building a one page landing page on Squarespace but have some trouble building a slideshow.
Here my website (slideshow is on the bottom of the page)
https://antoine-micoulet-wyze.squarespace.com/?r=69889373

Squarespace gives by default different options to position the text but only as a overlay on images. What I want is to have the description text for each image on the top as a title.

I found a similar question here but the CSS given is not working for me (and I just started learning CSS...)

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This is already built in to Squarespace by default unless I'm confused on what you're asking. To enable the description to show up as an overlay, you would checkbox that in the Gallery Block options, then make sure your images indeed have a description. See this link for details: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813728

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The pb is I don't want the description/title as a overlay but above (or outside) the image. This option is not a default option so need some css.

I actually repload the image with title directly into it.. it might not be the best solution but the easiest..